Find the number of integer points on a rotated ellipse
Let $n,l,k\in\mathbb{N}$ with $l>k$.
I want to find the number of integer points (or at least a nice upper bound of the number of integer points) on the following ellipse:
$$n(x^2-xy+y^2)-lx+ky=0.$$
Is there any way to find the number of integer points (or at least a nice upper bound of the number of integer points) on that ellipse in $n,l,k$?

Don't know if it will help but you can rational parametize it like this: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6eltnzdt5v  by studying the other intersection of a line with rational slope starting from a known point (the origin in this case).
